How to combine the data of two state into third state in Next js
I am using useState to set a state I have collected data in two different states (that are text and inputs ) now I want to add both states into a third state (that is alldata)
I have tried
const [alldata, setAlldata] = useState({})
 const [text, setText] = useState({ category: "product", });// there is more than one value
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([
    { item: "", quantity: "", rate: "", tax: "" },
  ]);
  setAlldata(
      {
        "text":text,
        "inputs":inputs,
      }
     )
  console.log(alldata)

but it's giving an empty object I want text and inputs in alldata that should look like
alldata:{
       text:{},
       inputs:{},
}

please suggest me any other way

Does this answer your question? The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately

That's not exactly what I meant.

I got your point. Thanks for clarifying in detail.

The setState is asynchronous, meaning the value will only be reflected on next render. Here's the detailed answer that dives deep into this behavior.
However, it could be an XY problem. If alldata purly depends on other states, using a useMemo would be preferred. It reflects the changes automatically when either of the states is mutated.
const [text, setText] = useState({ category: "product", });// there is more than one value
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([
  { item: "", quantity: "", rate: "", tax: "" },
]);

const alldata = useMemo(() => ({ text, inputs }), [text, inputs]);

console.log(alldata); // { text: { /* ... */ }, inputs: { /* ... */} }


that's exactly what I want on Render for any state change. Thanks for your reference.
